# String Return in PHP..... with SQL

Tags: php

Am having a problem with my PHP.   I have a for loop as below:

```
$todays_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
for ($k=0; $k < $_SESSION[CampaignTrax]; $k++) {
                        $numIncrement = $k +1;

$artistConcentrate = '$_POST[ArtistField_'.$numIncrement.']';
$titleConcentrate = '$_POST[TitleField_'.$numIncrement.']';
$mixConcentrate = '$_POST[MixField_'.$numIncrement.']';

$query2 = "INSERT INTO trackdata (promo_ID, track_orderno, track_dateofcreation, track_artist, track_title, track_mix, track_promo_title) VALUES('$_SESSION[promo_ID]', '$numIncrement', '$todays_date', '{$artistConcentrate}', '$titleConcentrate', '$mixConcentrate', '$_SESSION[CampaignTitle]')";
mysql_query($query2) or die('Error in MySQL query. Here is the error message: '.mysql_error());

}
```

My problem is that the $artistConcetrate variable literally returns `$_POST[ArtistField_1]` and that value displays in the SQL table on PHPMyAdmin as so, any chance I can get it to actually return the value of what was submitted as `POST[ArtistField_1]`, as this will be auto incremented through the loop so `artistfield_2` etc will be inserted into the table.

I am aware of SQL injection problems that may occur from the above but will update my code after the solution has been found.

Many thanks for any advice on this.

CP

Comment: It's the array _keys_ you want to be concatenating in `$_POST`, not the entire PHP variable expression: `$_POST['AritistField_' . $numIncrement]`

Comment: "INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows." - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html so please build a `$query` in a loop and fire mysql_query only once after the loop with that `$query`..

Comment: Funny how people still invent hot water and append numbers to strings which are used to name array keys, when we have this awesome thingy called - array. What's so wrong by having `$_POST['ArtistField'][$numIncrement]`? It's so much cleaner for you to work with, not to mention it's much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$todays_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
for ($k=0; $k < $_SESSION[CampaignTrax]; $k++) {
                        $numIncrement = $k +1;

$artistConcentrate = $_POST["ArtistField_".$numIncrement];
$titleConcentrate = $_POST["TitleField_".$numIncrement];
$mixConcentrate = $_POST["MixField_".$numIncrement];

$query2 = "INSERT INTO trackdata (promo_ID, track_orderno, track_dateofcreation, track_artist, track_title, track_mix, track_promo_title) VALUES('".$_SESSION['promo_ID']."', '".$numIncrement."', '".$todays_date."', '".$artistConcentrate."', '".$titleConcentrate."', '".$mixConcentrate."', '".$_SESSION['CampaignTitle']."')";
mysql_query($query2) or die('Error in MySQL query. Here is the error message: '.mysql_error());

}
```

Comment: Whizzkid you definitely live up to your name, that worked perfectly.  The numbers are inserted into my table and increment in order.

Comment: @ChrisP Nice to hear that, please mark this answer as accepted by clicking the tick on the left.

Answer (score 0):

```
$artistConcentrate = '$_POST[ArtistField_'.$numIncrement.']';
$titleConcentrate = '$_POST[TitleField_'.$numIncrement.']';
$mixConcentrate = '$_POST[MixField_'.$numIncrement.']';

$query2 = "INSERT INTO trackdata (promo_ID, track_orderno, track_dateofcreation, track_artist, track_title, track_mix, track_promo_title) VALUES('$_SESSION[promo_ID]', '$numIncrement', '$todays_date', '{$artistConcentrate}', '$titleConcentrate', '$mixConcentrate', '$_SESSION[CampaignTitle]')";
```

should be

```
$artistConcentrate = $_POST[ArtistField_'.$numIncrement.'];
$titleConcentrate = $_POST[TitleField_'.$numIncrement.'];
$mixConcentrate = $_POST[MixField_'.$numIncrement.'];

$query2 = "INSERT INTO trackdata (promo_ID, track_orderno, track_dateofcreation, track_artist, track_title, track_mix, track_promo_title) VALUES('".$_SESSION[promo_ID]."', '".$numIncrement."', '".$todays_date."', '".$artistConcentrate."', '".$titleConcentrate."', '".$mixConcentrate."', '".$_SESSION[CampaignTitle]."')";
```

Comment: No it shouldn't be that, take a look again what you did.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql_real_escape_string function for this purpose:-

Here is the documentation link:-
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

In your code you can do:-

```
$todays_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
for ($k=0; $k < $_SESSION[CampaignTrax]; $k++) {
                        $numIncrement = $k +1;

$artistConcentrate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ArtistField_'.$numIncrement]);
$titleConcentrate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['TitleField_'.$numIncrement]);
$mixConcentrate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['MixField_'.$numIncrement]);

$query2 = "INSERT INTO trackdata (promo_ID, track_orderno, track_dateofcreation, track_artist, track_title, track_mix, track_promo_title) VALUES('$_SESSION[promo_ID]', '$numIncrement', '$todays_date', '{$artistConcentrate}', '$titleConcentrate', '$mixConcentrate', '$_SESSION[CampaignTitle]')";
mysql_query($query2) or die('Error in MySQL query. Here is the error message: '.mysql_error());

}
```

Do remember to check mysql_set_charset() which would affect the result. Study documentation link given above.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying @whizzzkid Code:

```
$todays_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$query2 = "INSERT INTO trackdata (promo_ID, track_orderno, track_dateofcreation, track_artist, track_title, track_mix, track_promo_title) VALUES ";
for ($k=0; $k < $_SESSION[CampaignTrax]; $k++) {
                        $numIncrement = $k +1;

    $artistConcentrate = $_POST["ArtistField_".$numIncrement];
    $titleConcentrate = $_POST["TitleField_".$numIncrement];
    $mixConcentrate = $_POST["MixField_".$numIncrement];

    $query2 .= "(".$_SESSION['promo_ID']."', '".$numIncrement."', '".$todays_date."', '".$artistConcentrate."', '".$titleConcentrate."', '".$mixConcentrate."', '".$_SESSION['CampaignTitle']."'),";

}
$query2 = substr($query2, 0, -1);
mysql_query($query2) or die('Error in MySQL query. Here is the error message: '.mysql_error());
```

This fires `mysql_query` only once.